Questions on Basic Data Cleansing For Linear Regression
I'm following some tutorials on doing some linear regression and as I was building my notebook, I'm working on outlier detection and amongst the techniques described for doing outlier detection, one of them involved calculating the Standard Deviation, but for this I need to know if my columns are of Gaussian distribution. I'm aware that there are different techniques like:
Histograms
KDE Plot
Q-Q Plot
Kolomogorov-Smirnov Test
Shapiro-Wilk Test
D'Agostino and Pearson's Test
And I bet there are a few more as well. So what is the best one to use? I guess Histograms just give a clue but do not show the real intention. What is the standard practice to identify if the dataset is Gaussian or not? For example, I plotted the histogram for the Boston dataset and for the RM column which is the average number of rooms per dwelling, I see that it is a Gaussian distribution:

But when I used the shapiro and kstest, it says that RM is not Gaussian!
for i in X.columns:
    print(f'{i}: {"Not Gaussian" if shapiro(X[i])[1]<0.05 else "Gaussian"}  {shapiro(X[i])}')
    print(f'{i}: {"Not Gaussian" if kstest(X[i].values,"norm")[1]<0.05 else "Gaussian"}  {kstest(X[i].values,"norm")}')

The code above prints:
RM: Not Gaussian  ShapiroResult(statistic=0.9608722575483464, pvalue=2.411976537849353e-10)
RM: Not Gaussian  KstestResult(statistic=0.9998152774582629, pvalue=0.0, statistic_location=3.561, statistic_sign=-1)

How could this be? What should I trust?
Additionally, I calculated the number of zeros and NaN which looks like this:
Column ZN: Zeros = 372, NaNs = 0
Column CHAS: Zeros = 471, NaNs = 0

Looking into the meaning of these columns:
ZN - proportion of residential land zoned for lots over 25,000 sq.ft.
CHAS - Charles River dummy variable (1 if tract bounds river; 0 otherwise)

How do I make the decision to have them or ignore them as feature columns?

I need to know if my columns are of Guassian distribution What is it that you are assessing for normality, the independent variables?

See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538561/relevance-of-assumption-of-normality-ways-to-check-and-reading-recommendations/538566#538566

As nothing in reality is precisely normal, any normality test will (correctly) reject normality with a large enough data set, but that doesn't necessarily mean that you can't do your regression, see the already given answer and my link. Regarding outliers, most importantly do not delete outliers unless you know that they are erroneous from background information. Deleting valid observations just because they look outlying will bias and invalidate your analysis.

I'm not sure what resources you are following, but I fear they may not be very good ones.
First, it appears that you're plotting the marginal distribution of the outcome.  You may be doing this to determine if the data are "normal" or Gaussian.  However, a histogram shows you the marginal distribution of the outcome, whereas regression concerns the conditional distribution.  You're plotting the wrong thing, you should be plotting the residuals as opposed to the outcome.
Moreover, the Gaussian assumption is perhaps the least important assumption for linear regression (to the extent it is an assumption at all.  All relevant properties of the test statistics can be shown to exist even in the case where the conditional distribution is not Gaussian, so long as we have large samples.  See chapter 5 of Wooldridge's "Introductory Econometrics").
However, if you feel compelled to assess if the residuals have some distribution which resembles a Gaussian, my recommendation would be the QQ plot for the following reasons:

KDEs are themselves tiny models and can obfuscate important aspects of the data, such as boundedness above/below some value.

Hypothesis tests for normality are either completely underpowered or have so much power that they will reject even nominal departures from normality.  Such rejections are potentially false alarms, since the assumption of normality could be made with impunity.

The QQ plot is nice because you get to see tail behaviour as compared to your chosen distribution quite readily.  Unlike the histogram, which bins data (again, potentially hiding aspects if your data), the QQ plot plots all data points as they are without arbitrary binning.


Again, it bears repeating that the gaussian assumption is perhaps the least important assumption for regression.  However, if you insist on evaluating said assumption, I would generally stay away from hypothesis tests for normality and instead use a QQ plot.

I agree 100%. QQ plots (or, in this case, quantile normal plots) do take some practice to interpret, but it's worth it, and not just for this purpose.
