Statistical testing in R
What kind of statistical testing, with a corresponding example code in R, would you use to compare the nitrate concentrations of two different locations (with both many different sub-locations), at three different depths? The data is not normally distributed and therefore requires non-parametric testing.
Tried Kruskal-Wallis. Is this correct?

The distribution of the data is not relevant. The conditional distribution (the residuals) is relevant. It is not obvious that a non-parametric test is required. In fact, for nitrate concentrations I wouldn't expect that. Please consult a statistician.

"... with ... corresponding exampe code...": Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code for you, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it for yourself. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

A simple two-way ANOVA might well be sufficient. Possibly a mixed or hierarchical model to account for the clustering into two locations you have. As Roland writes, whether the data are normally distributed is quite irrelevant. Can you provide more information? How much data do you have? How many sub-locations? What is your scientific question?

Regarding "non-normality" of data also see this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538561/relevance-of-assumption-of-normality-ways-to-check-and-reading-recommendations/538566#538566
