Data passing all linearity assumptions except normality. What should my next steps be?
I am required to build models for a series of datasets which all have the same issue.
Edit: An example of one of my datasets is displayed in the image below, with a linear regression line fitted to it. It is volume (y) vs datetime (x) and the goal is to determine 1. if there is a notable change in volume over time and 2. (less important as 1 but still important) if there is, predict what volume may look like in future.

"Eyeballing" leads me to believe that the data are best fitted by a linear regression. My data appear to pass the homogeneity assumption (leveneTest pval > 0.05) and the linearity assumption (more research needs to be done for independence). No points have a Cook's distance of > 0.5 suggesting there are no highly influential outliers. However, my linear-appearing graphs are failing normality tests.
P-val is < 0.05 for shapiro.test(residuals(model)) checks.
The tails fall of the qq-plot:

I've tried square root & Box-Cox transformation of y, along with more robust modelling such as rlm and glm (on both transformed and untransformed data), but these all yield similar results.
I acknowledge that there is often no way to transform data to make it normal.
All my questions run along the same vein: What do I do next to model this data?
Could I still reasonably use a linear regression to model this data?
As most my datasets are > 500 points, could I reasonably claim C.L.T?
Is there another modelling method I could be using or something I've missed completely?

Welcome to Cross Validated! This is related.

The tails in your data are wider than that of your normal distribution. So you could try to use a distribution with a "fatter" tail: logistic distribution, Student's T distribution, ..., up to a Cauchy distribution.

Can you clarify why you regard normality as a "linearity check" (per the title)? You can certainly have linearity (whether you mean the conditional mean of y with x's or of the linear predictor as a function of the parameters) without normality.

It is unsurprising that the Shapiro-Wilks test is significant: you have rather obvious departure from normality in the tails, and your sample size is large enough to detect this. Q: what do you want to do? Do you want to test parameters for significance, or are you more interesting in prediction, and if the latter, what exactly do you want to predict?

Pedantic detail:  The test named more fully here by @StephanKolassa is the Shapiro-Wilk test. The work of Martin B. Wilk and that of Samuel S. Wilks is often confused. See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2810/editing-questions-dos-and-donts/2814#2814 for various confusible author names within statistical science.

A good if not the best check of a appropriate fit  is that introduced to me and presumably many others in secondary school for scatter plots. A good model should detectably pass through the middle of the data -- where you are in difficulties if you can't identify what is the middle of the data. Simple plots to check are residual versus fitted and observed versus fitted (a calibration plot). These naturally can be used even with several predictors. It's unclear to me how many predictors you have.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538561/relevance-of-assumption-of-normality-ways-to-check-and-reading-recommendations/538566#538566

What exactly does the first plot show?

Re the actual question: one clear next step is to examine the obviously outlying data, as represented by the points in the original plot high above and below the regression line and as reflected in the curved tips of the qq plot.  What do those data mean for you?

@Glen_b by linearity check I meant the assumptions for linearity

@ChristianHennig the first plot is one of the datasets I'm working with, with datetime on the x axis over the course of a few years and volume on the y axis

@StephanKolassa the x axis of the graph is datetime, and the y is volume. The goal is to determine if there is a significant change in the volume of points over the course of a few years. Prediction may become relevant if it does show a significant change (a significant slope) in the linear model (which that model does, but also that feels a little suspicious as both the highs got higher and the lows got lower, just the concentration of points has decreased over time). I'm new to statistics and don't have the language to explain that but it may need to be a seperate internet rabbit-hole / post

@Woolynik normality is not an "assumption for linearity" in any of the senses that seem to be relevant here. It's an assumption related to deriving critical values that attain the selected type I error rate (rejection rate when H0 is true).

@Woolynik Note that significance tests with large amounts of data can easily give you a significant result even if the effect (regression slope here) is in fact very small. This is not due to any issue with assumptions, rather this is part of the characteristic of statistical tests. Even if significant you have to decide whether the effect is strong enough to be considered meaningful in your application. Just saying...

Some general issues:

Model assumptions generally don't hold precisely in reality, and the idea that they have to hold is wrong (otherwise model-based methods could never be used). A model is an idealisation that is used for a reason (you didn't write about your aims of modeling, which is essential for assessing whether a certain model is a good one).  Model assumptions specify ideal conditions under which certain methods have good theoretical properties, but this doesn't mean that the models and methods can't be applied if model assumptions aren't fulfilled.

One thing to know about significance tests is that not rejecting the null hypothesis doesn't mean that the null hypothesis is true. Consequently this also means that "passing" a misspecification test such as Levene or Shapiro-Wilk does not mean that the tested model assumption is fulfilled.

These misspecification tests are of rather limited use in diagnosing model assumptions, because it may happen that violations of assumptions detected by them are rather harmless, and it may also happen that they miss issues that are problematic (such as leverage points). I'm not saying one shouldn't look at them, but simply saying "the model is OK" if they don't reject and "the model is bad and needs changing" if they reject is not appropriate. Always consider visual displays that may tell you more about what goes on in your data.

Note that changing the data based on diagnostics computed on the very same data (for example by transformation or deleting outliers) technically invalidates standard inference (such as regression t-tests after transformation), because standard inference assumes that no such thing has been done. It may occasionally be better to live with this problem rather than sticking to a model that is grossly wrong and misleading (model assumptions are not precisely fulfilled anyway, so it may not be the most deadly of statistical sins to invalidate them by data dependent decision making - don't read this as an encouragement to fish for significance though), but regularly transforming or changing the data in case some test reveals a small deviation from some assumption will most likely do more harm than good.


Regarding your data:

If the only problem visible in your data is the non-normality as shown in the QQ-plot and assuming that dimensionality is low (so that you have a healthy amount of data for the number of parameters you want to fit), the LS-estimator based on normality may very well do an OK job here, maybe with slightly lower power than under normality, which should not be a disaster. The deviation from normality looks fairly harmless given the number of observations you have (the Central Limit Theorem may make the behaviour of the LS-estimator somewhat close to a situation in which normality actually holds). But I say this under the proviso that there are no further problems in the data which we can't see based on the information given in the question. I'd certainly look at more diagnostic plots.

Robust regression estimators rely less on normality and can deal with some issues such as outliers and a more heavy tailed error distribution well, which may well be the case here. You may try an MM-estimator as computed by R-function lmrob in R-package robustbase. This also comes with some more visual diagnostics that may help you to spot outliers and leverage points, which sometimes cannot be seen from classical diagnostic plots. If you compare the MM- and the LS-estimator and the results agree largely, this should add some credibility to these results.



You may want to look at this blog, which gives an excellent, and succinct, review of the assumptions behind Linear Regression (or rather, the classical linear regression model, aka OLS). It then has further links which go into more details about each assumption.
In it you will read that the normality of the residuals assumption is probably the least important of all the assumptions, in the sense that the OLS estimator will still be BLUE, even if that assumption is not met. In addition, for large sample sizes (relative to your number of predictors, which we do not know... But at 500, one would think you are getting there), the normality assumption can be ignored, thanks to the CLT.
If all you want to do is create the "best" model (best in the OLS sense), and use the model to make predictions, or calibrate some data, etc. you really do not need the normality assumption. But if you want to get CI's for the $\beta$'s, or prediction intervals, etc., and do not think that the CLT would help, then yes, you would need normality of the residuals.
Last, do not transform your data. You would have to transform the Y and the X's, but they do not need to be normal (the residuals do); and if you did, you could not back-transform the CIs and PIs, these would be impossible to interpret, so the situation would be worse than living with the non-normality of the residuals.
